# How to remove similar folder from multiple locations in terminal

Tags: zsh, wildcards, rm

I have a folder 'reg_standard' nested within 68 different folders that I want to remove. The path to this folder looks something like:

```
/Volumes/.../sub-???/run_?.feat/reg_standard
```

where `'?'` is a stand-in for all the different folders that start with 'sub' or 'run'. For example, I have sub-101, sub-102, sub-162 (34 in total) and run_1 and run_2 folders nested within each sub-???, making a total of 68 folders in total where reg_standard exists.

How can I remove this folder and all its contents efficiently? Do I use rm -r? or find ... - delete? I use MacOS.

Thank you!

Comment: Your shell is presumably `zsh`, right? What is the output of running `ps $$` in a terminal? Does that show `/bin/bash` or `/bin/zsh`?

Comment: Hi @terdon, thanks for the response! it shows -zsh under the column "COMMAND"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using the `find` utility.

Run it once and carefully review that it lists *just* the files that you would like to run the delete command on:

```
find . -type d -name reg_standard
```

If this works as expected, you can re-run the `find` command with the `-exec` option:

```
find . -type d -name reg_standard -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Be aware that it is very easy to remove unintended files like this.

The `find` utility is very powerful: the search can be tweaked to ensure you find just what you need. More info available at: `man find`

Answer (score 2):

In zsh,

```
rm -rf /Volumes/.../sub-<0-999>/run_<0-9>.feat/reg_standard(/oN)
```

Would remove those folders efficiently. Adjust the `<x-y>` ranges as required or replace with `???` to match any 3 characters (or non-characters) or `*` for any sequence of zero or more characters (or non-characters).